# How to change reduction order in racket(scheme)?

Tags: scheme, racket

I think, i got an issue due racket set wrong reduction order.

```
(and (not (null? (cadr tree)))
     (not (= 0 (car (cadr tree)))))
```

When `(cadr tree)` returns null, the issue occurs(car: contract violation).
Can you tell me how to change reduction order or what's wrong with my code?

The "tree" has form as a (list number '() '()).

Comment: With, for example, `(define tree (cons 'x (cons '() 'y)))` [so that `(null? (cadr tree))` is true], your code `(and (not (null? (cadr tree))) (not (= 0 (car (cadr tree)))))` returns #f.

Comment: I forgot to say, the "tree" is a list. For example (define tree (list 10 null null)).

Comment: I suggest providing a specific input for which you get an error, and the actual error message produced.

Comment: Your code works fine with the example you gave. Please include an example that doesn't work. (You have most likely built a malformed tree, where the first branch is not a list, such as `(list null 10 null)`
.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(and (not (null? (cadr tree))) (not (= 0 (car (cadr tree)))))
```

when you call this code with `(define tree (list 10 null null))` there's nothing wrong with your first part of your expression you're calling car of the cdr of tree which is (define tree (list 10 `null` null)) first null element but in your second part of your expression you're calling cadr of tree which is first null element in the list and car of that null which is not valid argument for car. if you provide an input like `(define tree (list 10 (list null) null))` this time you get an error for testing equality of zero and null. You have to provide an input like `(define tree (list 10 (list 10) null))` which is first element of tree which is a list has a number element to work this code properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
(and (pair? tree)
     (pair? (cdr tree))
     (pair? (cadr tree))
     (not (zero? (caadr tree))))
```

Your scheme implementation should provide *safe* operators, like `car-safe` that implicitly test for type.  You can use it as well.